# How to change routes in gatsby without Link component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I have a controlled form in react. When the user submits the form, in the `handleSubmit` run, In that function I want to redirect/take them to a new url or page, where url is same as their input value.

For example user types "hello", then when the form submits I want to take them to

> http://example.com/*hello*

It seems like `</Link>(gatsby)` component won't work in here. So how do I change route without a `Link` Component

This is for a search bar

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should import the navigate API to push/replace the history stack, in order to carry out navigation.

```
import { navigate } from 'gatsby'
```

And this is how you can use it, on your form submit method. It is similar to React-Router's `history.push()`.

```
submit() {
  // rest of your form logic
  navigate('/hello');
}
```

If you wish to replace the history stack, you may use `navigate('/hello', { replace: true })` instead.You may refer to the Gatsby Link [documentation](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/gatsby-link/) for more details.

Comment: one thing, After I redirect to the new page the back button works as expected. But when I refresh the redirected page and click the back button on the browser it says "Cannot read property 'page' of undefined"

Comment: looks like it expecting some props for the previous url, and its removed when I refresh the page. How do I prevent that

Comment: @ProttayRudra I don't think the router itself can help when it comes to that, as the component/app is remounted when you refresh. Hence, the state will be reset to its original.

Comment: can I pass the information via the "state" argument?

Comment: @ProttayRudra yes, you may, but it won't be persisted when you refresh.

Comment: If the data is important, you can create an endpoint an save it on your DB? If not, you can try storing the data on your localStorage?

Answer (score 3):

You can use Gatsby's [`navigate`](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/gatsby-link/#how-to-use-the-navigate-helper-function) helper function.

For example:

```
import React, { useState } from "react"
import { navigate } from "gatsby"

const Form = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("")

  return (
    <form
      onSubmit={event => {
        event.preventDefault()
        navigate(`/${value}`)
      }}
    >
      {/* here goes your input that sets its value to state with `setValue` */}
    </form>
  )
}
```